# Why is my Jersey filter not getting triggered?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am just testing out my first `Jersey` filter in my REST API. Please check the below code.

**AuthenticationFilter** - The Jersey Filter

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

//    @Context
//    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
    public AuthenticationFilter()
    {
        System.out.println("test printing");
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext crc) throws IOException
    {
        String headerString = crc.getHeaderString("Bearer");
        System.out.println("bluh: "+headerString);

        }
}
```

**Secured** - Just an interface for `Secured` `NameBinding` annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;


@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Secured {}
```

**UserJsonService** - Rest Call

```
@Path ("/user")
public class UserJSONService {

@GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Secured
    public Response test()
    {
       return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("sd").build();
    }
}
```

The problem here when I fire the `test` REST call, the filter is not getting triggered at all. I know that because nothing is getting printed in console as I wanted it to do.

I have made no changes in my `web.xml` file because I used annotation, but as for your information it is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ExampleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.ExampleServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ExampleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ExampleServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Is your `AuthenticationFilter` inside the package `rest` which you have configured in your web.xml?

Comment: @JustinJose: No. It is in package `filter`

Comment: And that's why. You can list multiple packages separated by comma. Note also that packages listed are scanned recursively. So maybe better option would be to use a root parent package and just list that root package. Normally that's how it's done

Comment: @peeskillet: Not clear, where do I have to list the package? I can move this `filter` package into `rest` as a sub package, is that is what meant?

Comment: You should either specify the `filter` package in web.xml or move your filter to `rest` package. You can specify multiple packages for `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` separated by ';'. For eg: `rest;filter` The problem I think is that Jersey only scan `rest` folder right now and it cannot find your filter there and hence it is not registered.

Comment: @PeakGen moving `filter` inside `rest` folder also should work

Comment: @JustinJose: Thanks. Please provide as an anser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both filter and service/resource should be present in the `rest` package or one of its sub folders. It is also possible to specify multiple packages delimited by ';'. For example: `rest;filter`.